# How to change size of react-apexchart's radar chart width and height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I am working on a project that shows some data on radar charts. But I can not figure out the size of radar chart. Currently, I am using react-apexcharts and its radar chart.

```
import { ApexOptions } from "apexcharts";
import React from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

type RadarChartProps = {
  series: ApexOptions["series"];
  categories: string[];
};

const RadarChart: React.FC<RadarChartProps> = (props) => {
  const options: ApexOptions = {
    chart: {
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%",
      type: "radar",
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      sparkline: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },

    xaxis: {
      categories: props.categories,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    grid: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
      },
    },

    plotOptions: {
      radar: {
        size: 140,
        polygons: {
          fill: {
            colors: ["#f8f8f8", "#fff"],
          },
        },
      },
    },
    markers: {
      size: 4,
      colors: ["#0000FF"], // Marker color for each series
      strokeWidth: 0,
    },
    tooltip: {
      y: {
        formatter(val: number, _opts?: any): string {
          return `${val}`;
        },
      },
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      position: "top",
      horizontalAlign: "right",
      fontSize: "14px",
    },
  };
  return <Chart options={options} series={props.series} type="radar" />;
};

export default RadarChart;
```

This is my code for the question above with the options.

[image]

this is an image of my code result. I need to change height and width higher than current size. but i did not find any answers about it from stackoverflow or github issues of react-apexcharts. If you faced into this issue can you give me solutions?

I want to change the size of my radar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies within the `plotOptions` property. You're setting the `size`, which ultimately restricts the graph from expanding inside the container. You need to remove the `size` property inside the `plotOptions`. Below is an example

```
plotOptions: {
    radar: {
        polygons: {
            fill: {
                colors: ["#f8f8f8", "#fff"],
            },
        },
    },
},
```